# Using fragment arguments for the entire activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-bundle

The best practice to instantiate a fragment is:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int someInt) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

Then via the `arguments` is available even if the OS recreates the fragment.

Question:
The `onCreate` already accepts a `Bundle` and we can use `saveInstanceState` to save the data. So what is the difference with the `Bundle` we set in the arguments?
If I keep using the `arguments` during the activity/fragment lifecycle and do not use the save/restore instance bundle would that create any problems?